# Where can i find NuGet.Clients documentation?

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to add Nuget package management to my newly developed IDE.
The github repository seems to have UI components [here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/dev/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.PackageManagement.UI/Xamls) 
but i can't find any resources for how to use it.

the only [documentation](https://daveaglick.com/posts/exploring-the-nuget-v3-libraries-part-1) i can find doesn't say anything about UI components

Answer (score 1):

As devNull pointed out, there is [a page in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk) saying that certain packages on nuget.org are provided and usable in your project. But this roughly corresponds to the projects under [src\NuGet.Core](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/dev/src/NuGet.Core).

The projects under [src\NuGet.Clients](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/dev/src/NuGet.Clients) are tools that we distribute as a product, but are not intended to be a library or reusable. The UI components are extremely tied to Visual Studio, depending on several other components in Visual Studio, so you would have to implement all the dependencies to be able to use the UI. In my opinion you'd be better off using the core packages and build your own UI on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

The [Nuget-Client-SDK](https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/d726681e71db1b983838857de35682bfb7689bc1/docs/reference/NuGet-Client-SDK.md) doc states:

> The API is evolving and not yet documented, but examples are available
>   on Dave Glick's blog.

So it appears that the blog post that you mentioned is the extent of documentation currently available for that library.

Comment: A better URL for the docs would be https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk